# Admob not working with webview

Tags: java, android, webview, admob

My problem is my app don't work anymore. But when I added admob. My webview don't show up anymore. I programmed my app in html and Css. Also now their are not adds showed to.

Main Activity.java

```js
package webbased.wingcrony.by.worldconqueror3tipsandtricks;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;


import static webbased.wingcrony.by.worldconqueror3tipsandtricks.R.id.activity_main_webview;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(activity_main_webview);


        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


    }

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("Main Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-HTTP-HOST-HERE]/main"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
    }

    
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        client.disconnect();
    }

}
```

Activity_main.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>





</RelativeLayout>
```

build.gradle file

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "webbased.wingcrony.by.worldconqueror3tipsandtricks"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 3
        versionName "3.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }


    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.6.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        return true
    }

    // `return void` removes the lint error: `Not all execution paths return a value`.
    return void
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="webbased.wingcrony.by.worldconqueror3tipsandtricks">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
    android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter><!-- ATTENTION: This intent was auto-generated. Follow instructions at
  https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio to publish your URLs. -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- ATTENTION: This data URL was auto-generated. We recommend that you use the HTTP scheme.
                  TODO: Change the host or pathPrefix as necessary. -->
                <data
                    android:host="[ENTER-YOUR-HTTP-HOST-HERE]"
                    android:pathPrefix="/main"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
     App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can anyone helpme so my webview app work with admob? 
I think I did something wrong. But I don't know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id1"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Use this code for AdView